# CSV to HTML Table using php

Tags: php, csv, html-table

I am trying to take data from my CSV file and use php to display it in an html table, sorted by customer last name. I have tried a couple things and it doesn't seem to be working.

The output I got is: [image]
Right now the format is last, first,address,city,district,postal code
How would i import this to an html table using php?

using this code.

```
if( ($handle = fopen( 'input.csv', 'r' )) !== false )
{
    $output = '<table>';
    while( ($data = fgetcsv( $handle )) !== false )
    {
        $output .= '<tr>';
        foreach( $data as $value )
        {
            $output .= sprintf( '<td>%s</td>', $value );
        }
        $output .= '</tr>';
    }
    fclose( $handle );
    $output .= '</table>';
}
echo $output;
```

Comment: What did you try? Where exactly is the problem?

Comment: I submitted the code I tried to use. @Dekel

Comment: Much better :) Please add the **output** and explain where/what is the problem.

Comment: There is not output, thats the problem. Just a blank page.

Comment: Are you sure the file is there and you can read it?

Comment: I know the file is in the correct directory. Not sure if I'm reading it though. How do i check if its even seeing it?

Comment: Turn on your error reporting. There's a high chance that reading the file doesn't work. I tried the code and it worked right away. Add an "else" statement and see if it fires.

Comment: Use the following code on the top of your script this will show you the exact error.
**
`ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);`
**
However, this doesn't make PHP to show parse errors - the only way to show those errors is to modify your php.ini with this line:

**display_errors = on**

Comment: Thank you, I'm super confused why its not working!

Comment: Okay I got it working now, any idea on how to make headers on the table now? using the above code? @Bokul

Comment: So you are able to find the problem and now you are getting data @BoostedMonkey

Comment: If it works - add the output (the html you generated)

Comment: @Dekel here ya go.

Comment: Your output should be HTML, not Image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your last comment you ask for table header so you can write code like below,

```
echo '<table border="1">';
echo '<thead>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<th>last</th>';
echo '<th>first</th>';
echo '<th>address</th>';
echo '<th>.....</th>';
echo '<th>......</th>';
echo '<th>.....</th>';
echo '</tr>';
echo '</thead>';
echo '<tbody>';

    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo '<tr>';

        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            if(empty($data[$c])) {
               $value = "&nbsp;";
            } else {
               $value = $data[$c];
            }                
            echo '<td>'.$value.'</td>';

        }
        echo '</tr>';

        $row++;
    }

    echo '</tbody></table>';
```

Answer (score -3):

try this code
maybe this one helps you

```
<?php

$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("info.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
   
    echo '<table border="1">';
   
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        if ($row == 1) {
            echo '<thead><tr>';
        }else{
            echo '<tr>';
        }
       
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            //echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
            if(empty($data[$c])) {
               $value = "&nbsp;";
            }else{
               $value = $data[$c];
            }
            if ($row == 1) {
                echo '<th>'.$value.'</th>';
            }else{
                echo '<td>'.$value.'</td>';
            }
        }
       
        if ($row == 1) {
            echo '</tr></thead><tbody>';
        }else{
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        $row++;
    }
   
    echo '</tbody></table>';
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```